# CSS style and Jscript is not reflecting properly in MS outlook 2007

Tags: javascript, html, css, outlook

I have attached the HTML code that i am trying to display in MS outlook 2007. It workes fine in Chrome, but when it comes to outlook its not working properly. How can i make this work in outlook ?

Can we use an alternative codes/tags instead of the one i used here, to make it work in MS outlook 2007 ? If so, please help me with it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>

<ol class="track-progress" data-steps="3">
   <li id="1">
     <span style="color:Black;font-weight:bold;font-size:70%">Submission</span>
     <i></i>
   </li><!--
--><li id="2">
     <span style="color:Black;font-weight:bold;font-size:70%">Approval</span>
   </li><!--
--><li id="3">
     <span style="color:Black;font-weight:bold;font-size:70%">Implementation</span>
   </li><!--
--><li id="4">
     <span style="color:Black;font-weight:bold;font-size:70%">Completed</span>
     <i></i>
   </li><!--
--><li id="5">
     <span style="color:Black;font-weight:bold;font-size:70%">Rejected</span>
     <i></i>
   </li>
 </ol></div>
 
<style>
.track-progress li > span {
  display: block;

  color: #0000;
  //font-weight: bold;
  //text-transform: uppercase;
}
.track-progress li > span:after,
.track-progress li > span:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  border: solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-width: 15px;
}

.track-progress li > span:after {
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-width: 20px;
}

.track-progress li > span:before {
  z-index: 2;
}
.track-progress li.done + li > span:before {
  border-left-color: #19832f;
  
}
.track-progress li.ongoing + li > span:before {
  border-left-color: #24d347;
}

.track-progress li:first-child > span:after,
.track-progress li:first-child > span:before {
  display: none;
}

.track-progress[data-steps="3"] li { width: 15%; }
.track-progress[data-steps="4"] li { width: 25%; }
.track-progress[data-steps="5"] li { width: 20%; }
.track-progress {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.track-progress li:first-child i,
.track-progress li:last-child i {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  border: solid transparent;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-width: 15px;
}

.track-progress li:last-child i {
  left: auto;
  right: -15px;

  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}
.track-progress li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;

  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;

  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
</style>

<script>
var firstName = "Planning";
if (firstName === "Draft") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "#81C5F1";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
}
if (firstName === "In Cart") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "#81C5F1";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
}
if (firstName === "In Review") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "#81C5F1";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
}
if (firstName === "Submitted") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "#81C5F1";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
}
if (firstName === "Waiting Approval") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#81C5F1";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
}
if (firstName === "Pending") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "#81C5F1";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
}
if (firstName === "Planning") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "#81C5F1";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
}
if (firstName === "In Progress") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "#81C5F1";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
}
if (firstName === "Completed") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "#81C5F1";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
}
if (firstName === "Closed") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "#77E765";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "#81C5F1";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
}
if (firstName === "Rejected") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "#F74141";
}
if (firstName === "Cancelled") {
 document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("3").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("4").style.backgroundColor = "f0f0f0";
 document.getElementById("5").style.backgroundColor = "#F74141";
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can i make this work in outlook ?

You need to read through the following resource: [Supported HTML Elements, Attributes, and Cascading Style Sheet Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx#Supported%20HTML%20Elements,%20Attributes,%20and%20Cascading%20Style%20Sheet%20Properties) or [Working with Outlook HTMLBody – a guide for Office developers](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2015/02/23/outlook-htmlbody-guide/). By briefly looking at your HTML code and what Outlook would allow, there a lot of unsupported tags you are using. For example: "display", "overflow", etc. Please clean up your HTML and make it compatible with what OUTLOOK able to render. You may also use available online [Outlook HTML Email Online Validator](http://jonathanaquino.com/outlook-html-email-validator.php). I am not aware how accurate it is, but this is definitely good way to start.

> Can we use an alternative codes/tags instead of the one i used here, to make it work in MS outlook 2007 ?

Yes, this is exactly what you should do. Use supported CSS styles and HTML tags.

> If so, please help me with it.

This is what you should do as developer. This is probably the work you are paid for as well. So simply do it according the resource provided, do not expect somebody would write the code for you.