# Microsoft Office truncating line from HTML source

Tags: html, ms-office

In an application I'm providing a copy-to-clipboard functionality that exports HTML code of colored, formatted text for import in office programs. Here's a minimal example:

```
<html><body><pre style="font-family:monospace;">
  A  B  C
1 <span style="background-color:blue">#      </span>
</pre></body></html>
```

This code imports nicely into LibreOffice 4.3 showing a blue background from column A to C, but Microsoft Office (different versions tested) truncates the content of the span tag by its trailing spaces.

I tried to replace all whitespaces by non breakable spaces, but these are not interpreted by LibreOffice.

Is there another way to export this in a way that's more compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will use "&#160;" instead of "&nbsp;", it should work in LibreOffice (after your own verification with this app) and it does work with Microsoft Office (verified it myself).

> Is there another way to export this in a way that's more compatible?

Reliable and most simple way to achieve the same view is to use regular `<table>` tag. For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan='3' style='background-color:blue;'>#</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the table is imported as table, not text. Which is no option here not only because the table is much bigger than the text-only representation, but also for utilization.

Comment: Well, I understand, you have requirements, but the way to keep white-space is to use "width" and "display" styles, which are not supported by Outlook rendering engine. "& nbsp;" is another way, but you said it doesn't work with LibreOffice. You may see Outlook capabilities for rendering as I answered [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766705/css-style-and-jscript-is-not-reflecting-properly-in-ms-outlook-2007/42767464#42767464). Not much you can do other than re-design something with HTML itself (not styles).

Comment: if you will use "&#160;" instead of "&nbsp;", is this gonna work in LibreOffice? I cannot try it myself. Outlook works.

Comment: Yep, the numerical representation works in LibreOffice and Word. Thanks, make this an answer and I'm glad to accept it.